# Swift Generic URLRequest

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a createRequest function that I can re-use for all my networking calls, some require posting JSON and other don't so I was thinking of creating a function that takes an optional generic object; something in theory like this:

```
struct Person: Codable {

var fName: String
var lName: String

}

struct Location: Codable {

 var city: String
 var state: String

}

let data = Person(fName: "John", lName: "Smith")
let location = Location(city: "Atlanta", state: "Georgia")

createRequest(withData: data)
createRequest(withData: location)

 private func createRequest(withData:T) throws -> URLRequest { 

        var newRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(withUrl)")!)

        newRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

       if let data = withData {

            newRequest.setBody = data

         }

        if withAPIKey {

            newRequest.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKEY")

        }

        return newRequest

    }
```

I would like to return the URLRequest with the option of passing different JSON objects this function. I read that you cant do it this way unless you define the type on the return function but I can't define my object in the return.

Comment: "but I can't define my object in the return" what constrains you from explicitly setting the resulting type?

Comment: @LeoDabus I have multiple JSON objects that I may pass into the function. The result will always be a urlrequest.

Comment: Exactly why do you need the generic? The only way to can set the body is with a Data, right? So surely your method should just take a Data (which to be sure can be Optional). — Also what is `setBody`? URLRequest has no such property.

Comment: @matt because `data` is one of a couple json objects that I have defined. It could be any of them.

Comment: So what? It's still a Data right? What else could it be? There is no such thing as a "json object".

Comment: Correct, it is one of a few different structs that I have defined

Comment: _What_ is "a struct that you have defined"? You can't define URLRequest, it already exists. And your only use of `data` seems to have something to do with URLRequest. This all appears to be sheer nonsense. Please feel free to prove me wrong by showing more code.

Comment: @matt I have edited my question and am trying to do something like the above. I thought I needed to have a generic since I could be passing different structs to the function.

Comment: But how will hand a struct to a URLRequest? No, you will encode the struct into a Data first. That’s what Encodable is for.

Comment: @Nick Looks like your object needs to take a `Encodable`, not a `T`, and the label `withData:` is a misnomer, because that parameter won't have type `Data`. `withBody:` would work better.

Comment: `URL(string: "\(withUrl)")!` ... don't do this.

Comment: @matt, I was hoping to pass the struct to the function and then in the function decode it into data and add to the urlRequest

Comment: Then pass an Encodable not a generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: This code's a mess of inconsistent indentation and unnecessary whitespace (it reads like a double-spaced essay lol), I cleaned it up.

Looks like your function needs to take a `T`, but not just any `T`, but one that is constrained to being `Encodable`. This is a common observation: more general generic parameters are compatible with more types, but can do we less with them. By containing `T` to `Encodable`, we can use it with `JSONEncoder.encode`.

The label `withData:` is a misnomer, because that parameter won't have type `Data`. Something like `withBody:` would work better.

```
import Foundation

struct Person: Codable {
    var fName: String
    var lName: String
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var city: String
    var state: String
}

// stubs for making compilation succeed
let apiKey = "dummy"
let withAPIKey = true
enum HTTPMethod: String { case GET } 

private func createRequest<Body: Encodable>(method: HTTPMethod, url: URL, withBody body: Body) throws -> URLRequest { 

    var newRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    newRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    newRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(body)

    if withAPIKey {
        newRequest.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKEY")
    }

    return newRequest
}

let data = Person(fName: "John", lName: "Smith")
let location = Location(city: "Atlanta", state: "Georgia")
```

Comment: @LeoDabus The first one was left over from copy pasting. "btw why repeating body in the name with body: would read better" -> I wasn't sure either way. On the call site, any encodable type can be used, so it's no immediately obvious that it's the body (as opposed to a header, for example).

Comment: I am getting an error on the `try JSONEncoder` line in your above answer that says `Protocol type Encodable cannot conform to Encodable because only concrete types can conform to protocols`. Looks like you need to downcast `withBody`by adding `encode(withBody as! Person)`.

Comment: @Nick I don't understand the issue with what little you've said. Could you elaborate more? Forcing a down cast is certainly not the right call.

Comment: I am saying your answer does not work, it gives an error on this line: `newRequest.setBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(body)`

Comment: @Nick I was confused because you had marked the answer as accepted. I figured it out, turns out this does require a generic, after all.

Comment: Is it possible to use a generic but have it be optional? Some requests I won't be passing any data to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192933/discussion-between-alexander-and-nick).